# if null value subquery returning null

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, subquery, dbnull

I have a mysql query:

```
select userid, sum(fees)
from table1
where userid in (
  select distinct userid
  from table2
  where condition1 = 2
  and condition2 =5
)
group by userid;
```

Now, it works, but if the sum(fee) is null i don't have a value, even if the userid is present in the subselect.
Is there a way to have the proper userid (the one in the subselect), and 0 as sum , if a null value in the first select return null?

```
1, 100
2, 239
3, 0
4, 453
(in this case 3 is present in the subselect, but the sum is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COALESCE()` or `IF(isnull(fees), true, false)`.

[Coalesce](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

[Isnull()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull)

Answer (score 0):

use isnull function.
select userid, sum(isnull(fees,0))
from table1
where userid in (
  select distinct userid
  from table2
  where condition1 = 2
  and condition2 =5
)
group by userid;

Comment: Use code formater to differentiate code from other description

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
select userid, COALESCE(sum(fees), 0)
from table1
where userid in (
 select distinct userid
 from table2
 where condition1 = 2
 and condition2 =5
)
group by userid;
```

As per the function "return the first parameter, unless it's null in which case return the second parameter" (0 in this case).

More on **Coalesce** is here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

**Update:**

```
select t1.userid, COALESCE(sum(t1.fees), 0)
from table2 t2 left outer     join table1 t1 on 
T2.userid = t1.userid

 where t2.condition1 = 2
 and t2.condition2 =5

 group by t1.userid;
```

Comment: it is OK.
Now, the userid is present in the subselect but is it not present in the first select. As a result i have NULL, 0 . Example: if i write 

select userid, COALESCE(sum(fees), 0)
from table1
where userid = 5000
group by userid;

i have null,0. Is there a way to have a result 5000,0 ?

Comment: Is userid=5000 present in both tables table1 and table2? Or is it present in table2 but not in table1

Comment: Can u try the above

Comment: you ignored the distinct in the subquery, if it was there for a reason, your sums will be wrong. And it should be t2.userid in the select list/group by

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting no row for case 3 since there is no row for the user in table1, so you have to use an outer join, something like

```
 select users.userid , coalesce(sum(fees),0) from
 (select distinct(userid) from table2
    where condition1 = 2
      and condition2 =5) users
 left outer join table1 on table1.userid = users.userid
 group by users.userid
```

Comment: whats the error messag? the query doesn't assume fees in table2.

Comment: tested ok with postgress, and its standard sql, so what does mysql say

Comment: it was my mistake. it was exactly what i was looking for. Working perfectly